# list view with card view OnItemclickListner not working

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cardview

I am new to android ,I am created List view and card view list image when  click item it not working any one please how to achive this,my list was displayed with card Veiw fine but when I  click my it my OnClick was not working any one help me

here my java code

```
public class ALL extends Fragment { 

private ListAdapter mAdapter;

    private ArrayList<String> listCountry;
    private ArrayList<Integer> listFlag;
    private ListView listview;

     @Override

     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout_one, container, false);

         prepareList();        
        mAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), listCountry, listFlag);
        //Missed code to here
        listview = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_listView);
        listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                switch(position){
                case 0:             
                Intent one=new Intent(getActivity(),India.class);
                startActivity(one);
                break;          

                case 1:             

                    Intent two=new Intent(getActivity(),USA.class);
                    startActivity(two);
                    break;              
                case 2:
                    Intent three=new Intent(getActivity(),kanda.class);
                    startActivity(three);
                    break; 
                case 3:                 
                    Intent four=new Intent(getActivity(),resp.class);
                    startActivity(four);
                    break;              
                case 4:                 
                    Intent five=new Intent(getActivity(),koria.class);
                    startActivity(five);
                    break;                  
                case 5:                 
                    Intent six=new Intent(getActivity(),newzlan.class);
                    startActivity(six);
                    break;                  
                case 6:                 
                    Intent seven=new Intent(getActivity(),Dubai.class);
                    startActivity(seven);
                    break;                  
                case 7:                 
                    Intent eight=new Intent(getActivity(),canad.class);
                    startActivity(eight);
                    break;                  
                 case 8:                        
                        Intent nine=new Intent(getActivity(),mexico.class);
                        startActivity(nine);
                        break;              

                }

            }
        });

         return rootView;         
     }

     public void prepareList()
        {
            listCountry = new ArrayList<String>();

            listCountry.add("india.in");
            listCountry.add("Usa.com");
            listCountry.add("Londan.com");
            listCountry.add("Uh=ganda.com");
            listCountry.add("Region.com");
            listCountry.add("canada.com");
            listCountry.add("southafrica.in");
            listCountry.add("mixico.com");
            listCountry.add("turki.com");           


            listFlag = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            listFlag.add(R.drawable.India);
            listFlag.add(R.drawable.USA);
            listFlag.add(R.drawable.AUS);
            listFlag.add(R.drawable.Canda);
            listFlag.add(R.drawable.newzland);
            listFlag.add(R.drawable.Dubai);
            listFlag.add(R.drawable.nws);
            listFlag.add(R.drawable.kan);
            listFlag.add(R.drawable.mal);           

        }
}
```

My ListAdapter class

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{   

    private ArrayList<String> listCountry;
    private ArrayList<Integer> listFlag;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private static Context mcontext;

    public ListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> listCountry, ArrayList<Integer> listFlag)
    {
        super();
        this.listCountry = listCountry;
        this.listFlag = listFlag;
        this.mcontext = context;
    }       

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listCountry.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listCountry.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }  
    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView imgViewFlag;
        public TextView txtViewTitle;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         ViewHolder view;

// TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if(convertView==null)
        {
             inflater =  (LayoutInflater)mcontext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_design, null);

            view.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nature);
            view.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);

            convertView.setTag(view);
        }
        else
        {
            view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        view.txtViewTitle.setText(listCountry.get(position));
        view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(listFlag.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }
    }
```

list_item_design

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
    card_view:cardElevation="0.001dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"

            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_nature"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="25dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:textColor="#24B9FE"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Test Test Test Test Test Test Test"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_thumbnail"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_nature"
        android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
        android:background="#24B9FE"
        android:text="Book"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: You don't need to use "am" in every sentence.

Comment: provide your list_item_design xml

Comment: posted above  my list_item_design xml @Waleed sarawar